# error logs in app service does not show in azure blobs

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHKiW.png)I am trying to generate error logs in app service and store them in azure blobs.

In app service logs, I have turned on the option for blob storage in application logging.

After that, I am generating the 500 error as well as 503 and (divide by zero) error.

These error should get displayed in application log stream as well as get stored to blob storage.
But nothing is happening.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Application logging(Blob) level in your picture is too low. You could set it as `Verbose`. Then you could find log in blob.

[image]

Comment: When I set it to Verbose, blob file is generated but still its not giving error info.
Its giving information, warning and verbose but no error

Comment: When you in asp.net, you could use `System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError` to get error message. You generate 500 error, but system does not spot it as error, it just view it as info. So you could use try catch and add error message in `Trace.TraceError`.

Comment: Thanks for that. What you are suggesting is manual as I have to write separate command for that. Can you suggest some other error I can generate so that it shows up in the blob file?

Comment: Here you've got something like dropped database connections or the inability to access a file or service. Refer to this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/logging-levels-what-they-are-and-how-they-help-you).